# How to perform calculations on the same variable based on factor levels of 2 other variables?

Tags: r

I have the following information in a dataframe

```
  Gender  EducationLevel   Income(mean) 
   Male     Low             10
   Male     High            12
   Female   Low
```

And I would like to create a separate variable in which I will have subtracted the Mean Income between men who belong to High and to Low Educational level (and then do the same for women).
How is it possible through R code without doing it manually?

I am very confused on how because there are two if clauses: if Gender is Male and then subtract 
the Income(mean) of (EducationLevel="High")-(EducationLevel="Low"), (Gender == "Male")

The new variable would look like this (without the EducationLevel info any more):

```
   Gender  Difference
    Male      2
    Female    3
```

Any help will be very much appreciated, I thought of using lapply but I am not experienced enough in R to be successful
I am not sure how to set the variable Income(mean) in the (EducationLevel="High")-(EducationLevel="Low") calculation.

Comment: You should provide raw, dummy data for Gender Female as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the way your raw data seem to be ordered, you may use `aggregate` and `diff`.

```
df <- read.table(text = "Gender  EducationLevel   Income(mean) 
Male     Low             10
Male     High            12
Female   Low 7
Female High 10", header = TRUE)

df
```

Note that "Income(mean)" is not a syntactically valid variable name and is converted by `read.table`. See `check.names` argument in `?read.table`.

```
setNames(aggregate(Income.mean. ~ Gender, data = df, diff), c("Gender", "Difference"))

#   Gender  Difference
# 1 Female           3
# 2   Male           2
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly! Not sure how it does it though, since I do not mention anywhere the variable EducationLevel..., but still it works. I know that the () are not acceptable as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I use simplified notation but essentially that's what you would have to do:

```
> df <- data.frame(g = c("m","m","f","f"), e = c("h","l","h","l"), i = sample(4,4))

> df
  g e i
1 m h 1
2 m l 4
3 f h 2
4 f l 3

> mean(df[df$g == "m" & df$e == "h","i"]) - mean(df[df$g == "m" & df$e == "l","i"])
[1] -3

> mean(df[df$g == "f" & df$e == "h","i"]) - mean(df[df$g == "f" & df$e == "l","i"])
[1] -1
```